# Use of VB.NET class in VB6 via interop requires class to have constructor?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, constructor, com-interop

When I try to create a `VB.NET` object via interop in `VB6`, I have noticed I get this error if my `VB.NET` class doesn't have a constructor:

> Error 430 - Class doesn't support automation

All I have to do is put an empty constructor in the `VB.NET` class, eg:

```
Public Sub New()

End Sub
```

and the error is avoided.  Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes. Com classes being wrapped in C# must have a parameterless constructor. This restriction travels both ways.

Answer (score 2):

VB6 creates objects through COM, using the class factory for a COM coclass.  The underlying method is IClassFactory::CreateInstance().  This method does not permit passing any arguments to the factory.  It therefore follows that the [ComVisible] .NET class must have a constructor that doesn't take any arguments.

.NET already creates a default constructor for a class, unless you specify a constructor yourself that takes arguments.  Which will never be used, you might as well remove it.  Now you also don't need the empty default constructor anymore.

Comment: I have found that I get the above error if I have no constructor.  The only way it seems to work is if a parameterless constructor is put in.